# How to use UNION ALL within while loop

Tags: t-sql

How should I use union all to get Result of a while loop in a set, so that I can use the same to fill data in a combo box.

Here is the Sql code in which I'm trying union all

```
Declare @start int = 1

While(@start <= 24)
Begin 
 (select @start as ColumnA) union All  ----need to fix this line
set @start = @start + 1 
End
```

Expected Ouput :

```
ColumnA
1
2
.
.
.
24(up to 24)
```

Comment: You cannot use `union all` like that. What DB engine do you use?

Comment: I hink you either need to rethink your approach or build it into a string dynamically with the SQL which you then can execute.

Comment: @allan s. Hansen : Tried something like this ( since I'm a beginner) But in this case it says select cannot be converted to data type int    
     set sql = 'select'            
     set sql = sql + ' ' + start + ' as columnA '

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive *common table expression* (cte) to produce the wanted result:

```
with cte (n) as 
(    
    values (1)              -- anchor
    union all 
    select n + 1 from cte   -- recursive
    where n < 24            -- terminate
)
select * from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution could be something along these lines. It is up to 100, however, it is not difficult to raise the limit

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) v(n)
)
SELECT 1 + ones.n + 10 * tens.n ColumnA  
FROM x ones,     x tens
WHERE ones.n + 10 * tens.n < 24
ORDER BY ColumnA
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to achieve 24 running numbers is this

```
SELECT TOP 24 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ColumnA
FROM master..spt_values --pick any table with a sufficient row-count
```

As you are a beginner, you should try to learn the *set-based* thinking right from the start. What your code shows, is *procedural* thinking.

With a *set-based* tool you must learn to think like your tool acts.

That means:

> no loops, no cursors, no *do this and than this and finally that*.

That means:

> Dear engine, I describe for you what I want to get and it is up to you how to solve this best.

### UPDATE

Just to show you, what *might* have worked (but again, loops are in most cases the wrong approach):

--I declare a table variable, which acts like a real table, but is gone when *out of scope*:

```
DECLARE @keepNumbers TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Nmbr INT);
```

--Your loop will insert the numbers one after the other

```
Declare @start int = 1

While(@start <= 24)
Begin 
    INSERT INTO @keepNumbers VALUES(@start);
    set @start = @start + 1 
End
```

--No you have a table containing all your numbers

```
SELECT Nmbr FROM @keepNumbers ORDER BY ID;
```